# How to change TimeFormat in java?

Tags: java, arrays

My requirement is for the below input to produce the expected output.

I have issue with the time format as mentioned start time and end time should match from the input

Input :

```
From date : 1/11/2020 10:00:00

End date : 30/11/2020 22:50:50
```

ouput should be :-

```
01/11/2020 10:00:00 to 10/11/2020 23:59:59 , 11/11/2020 00:00:00 to 20/11/2020 23:59:59 , 21/11/2020 00:00:00 to 30/11/2020 22:50:50
```

My code:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class DateTest {
    public static void printDaysInPeriod(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, int interval) {
        Map<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime> intervals = new TreeMap<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime>();
        while (start.isBefore(end)) {
            LocalDateTime intervalEnd = start.plusDays(interval - 1);
            intervals.put(start, intervalEnd);
            start = intervalEnd.plusDays(1);
        }
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss");
        List<String> intervalOutput = new ArrayList<>();
        intervals.entrySet().forEach(e -> intervalOutput.add(e.getKey().format(formatter) + " to " + e.getValue()));
        System.out.println(String.join(" , ", intervalOutput));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String startInterval = "2020-11-01 10:00:00";
        String endInterval = "2020-11-30 22:50:50";

        int interval = 10;
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:m:ss");
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse(startInterval, formatter);
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse(endInterval, formatter);
        printDaysInPeriod(start, end, interval);
    }
}
```

This is what my output from this code

```
 2020-11-01 10:00:00 to 2020-11-10T10:00 , 2020-11-11 10:00:00 to 2020-11-20T10:00 , 2020-11-21 10:00:00 to 2020-11-30T10:00
```

Comment: You said your input has "10:00:00" and "22:50:50" in it, but `startInterval` and `endInterval` doesn't have those times? Shouldn't you be taking `LocalDateTime`s, rather than `LocalDate`s  as input?

Comment: while parsing I am getting error , If I use LocalDatetime

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show _how_ you used `LocalDateTime`, and the error message you got.

Comment: I would highly recommend you go through the docs for `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` before choosing between one. If you are getting error using `LocalDateTime` it does not mean that your approach is wrong. Your comment is giving the impression that you want to brute force your result. Knowing the API that you want to use will always help you in writing correct code rather than working code.

Comment: A `Map<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime>` is a funny type for your collection of intervals. I’d design my own interval class.

Comment: Standard recommendations would be to use half-open intervals, so the output requirement should state `01/11/2020 10:00:00 to 11/11/2020 00:00:00 , 11/11/2020 00:00:00 to 21/11/2020 00:00:00`, etc. Meaning 01/11/2020 10:00:00 *inclusive* to 11/11/2020 00:00:00 *exclusive*, etc. It’s much cleaner, both conceptually and codingwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't set the time components of the bounds of the intervals. The lower bound of each interval *except the first* needs to be at 00:00 (`LocalTime.MIN`), and the upper bound of each interval *except the last* needs to be at 23:59 (`LocalTime.MAX`). We need to somehow detect those cases.

One way is:

```
while (start.isBefore(end)) {
    LocalDateTime intervalEnd = start.plusDays(interval - 1).with(LocalTime.MAX);
    intervals.put(start, intervalEnd.isBefore(end) ? intervalEnd : end);
    start = intervalEnd.plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.MIN);
}
```

Notice how the second argument to `put` is:

```
intervalEnd.isBefore(end) ? intervalEnd : end
```

This is how we detect whether this is the last interval. If it is the last interval (`intervalEnd` not before `end`), then we use `end` as the upper bound of that interval. This makes sure that it has the same *time* as `end`.

Also note that we are only setting the time of `start` to `MIN` *after* it has been put into the map. This makes sure that the time of the lower bound of the first interval is same as that of `start`.

You also forgot to call `format` on `e.getValue()`.

---

Actually, if you just want to print the string, you don't need the map. Just print directly in the loop:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss");
while (start.isBefore(end)) {
    LocalDateTime intervalEnd = start.plusDays(interval - 1).with(LocalTime.MAX);
    System.out.print(start.format(formatter));
    System.out.print(" to ");
  System.out.print(intervalEnd.isBefore(end) ?
        intervalEnd.format(formatter) + ", " :
        end.format(formatter));
    start = intervalEnd.plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.MIN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print time/date format in loop:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss");
while (start.isBefore(end)) {
    LocalDateTime intervalEnd = start.plusDays(interval - 1).with(LocalTime.MAX);
    System.out.print(start.format(formatter));
    System.out.print(" to ");
    System.out.print(intervalEnd.isBefore(end) ?
        intervalEnd.format(formatter) + ", " :
        end.format(formatter));
        start = intervalEnd.plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.MIN);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is clean code. Therefore I hope this is a reference.

```
class InteverOutput{
    private String startDateStr;
    private String endDateStr;

    public String getStartDateStr() {
        return startDateStr;
    }
    public void setStartDateStr(String startDateStr) {
        this.startDateStr = startDateStr;
    }
    public String getEndDateStr() {
        return endDateStr;
    }
    public void setEndDateStr(String endDateStr) {
        this.endDateStr = endDateStr;
    }   

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s to %s",startDateStr,endDateStr);
    }


}

public class DateTest { 
    public static void printDaysInPeriod(
                LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end, int interval) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
                 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss");
    
        //for output
        List<InteverOutput> outputs = new ArrayList<InteverOutput>();
    
        while (start.isBefore(end)) {
            InteverOutput inteverOutput = new InteverOutput();
        
            LocalDateTime intervalEnd = 
                 start.plusDays(interval1).with(LocalTime.MAX);

              inteverOutput.setStartDateStr(start.format(formatter).toString());
        
            if(!intervalEnd.isBefore(end)) {
                intervalEnd = end;
            }
        
           
          inteverOutput.setEndDateStr(intervalEnd.format(formatter).toString());
        
            start = intervalEnd.plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.MIN);
        
            outputs.add(inteverOutput);
        }
    
        // join ,
        String output = outputs.stream().map((s)-> 
                s.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    
        System.out.println(output); 
    
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String startInterval = "2020-11-01 10:00:00";
    String endInterval = "2020-11-30 22:50:50";

    int interval = 10;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:m:ss");
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse(startInterval, formatter);
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse(endInterval, formatter);
    printDaysInPeriod(start, end, interval);
}
```

}